# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

I just wrote a simple program to test tensorflow library in my windows 10.
It is running well but only problem is that I am not being able to use tensorboard to visualize graphs.

**Following is my code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_b")
c = tf.mul(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")
sess = tf.Session()
output = sess.run(e)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
writer.close()
sess.close()
```

**Error log**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5c6b380c18c8> in <module>()
      7 sess = tf.Session()
      8 output = sess.run(e)
----> 9 writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
     10 writer.close()
     11 sess.close()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.pyc in __init__(self, logdir, graph_def, max_queue, flush_secs)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.pyc in add_graph(self, graph_def, global_step)

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'
```

**Tensorflow version**

```
In[14:]:tf.__version__
Out[14]:'0.7.1'
```

**Tensorflow library upgrade**

When I tried to upgrade tensorflow library to latest 0.12 using pip in jupyter notebook it downloaded and installed lot of stuffs and after that I again tested the version but it was same.So I again tried to upgrade but it displayed following message.

Requirement already up-to date

How to get out of this mess?

Comment: TensorFlow 0.7.1 doesn't include support for Windows, so I'm not sure how you managed to get that far with it (perhaps you were using a Docker container?). This API was changed to accept `tf.Graph` instances before the first official Windows release (0.12) was made.